# jQuery Document Ready sometimes not executed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have issues with jquery code in *$(document).ready(function () {...});* sometimes not being executed when the page is loading.

How can I force the function to be executed? Or force the code to await for the function to be finished if it is related to async issues?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var fileReading = new Array();
            $.get('output.txt', function(data){
                     fileReading = data.split(',');
                     fileReadingLength = fileReading.length-1;
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#img1").attr({ "src": fileReading[fileReadingLength-1] });
               $("#img2").attr({ "src": fileReading[1] });
               $("fileReadingLength").text(fileReadingLength);
               for (i = 0; i <= fileReadingLength; i++) {
                  $('body').append('<br><img id="img"'+i+' src="'+fileReading[i]+'">')
               }
            });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      Number of images: <fileReadingLength></fileReadingLength> <br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not move the get inside the document ready and then run the code inside your document ready in your get so you know that you have the variables you need - https://jsfiddle.net/fh21dz9v/

Comment: @Debendra no, it is not. It exists so that you can put your code anywhere in the document.

Comment: Your provided code is working perfectly fine. Add a `console.log()` inside the `.ready` callback and you will see it is actually working.

Comment: It is okay to place anywhere but it has performance benefit if used inside at the end of document.

Comment: @Debendra no need for the document ready if you put your script there - the point of the document ready is that it can be put anywhere and will wait until the document is ready, if you put it at the end of the document, then it the dom is ready anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that since your `.get` is done asynchronously, for large files, `$(document).ready` fires before `fileReading` has elements. Why not move the `$(document).ready` into the `.get`, this is guaranteed to fire even if it's set after the document is ready.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var fileReading = new Array();
        $.get('output.txt', function(data){
            fileReading = data.split(',');
            fileReadingLength = fileReading.length-1;
            $(function () {
                $("#img1").attr({ "src": fileReading[fileReadingLength-1] });
                $("#img2").attr({ "src": fileReading[1] });
                $("fileReadingLength").text(fileReadingLength);
                for (i = 0; i <= fileReadingLength; i++) {
                    $('body').append('<br><img id="img"'+i+' src="'+fileReading[i]+'">')
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Number of images: <fileReadingLength></fileReadingLength> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: `$(document).ready(handler)` has been deprecated in favour of `$(handler)` since jQuery 3.0.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to modularity.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the great explanation also.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work sometime is because `$.get` is asynchronous. If the document is ready before the `$.get` block returns a response, then you will have no values for both `fileReading` and `fileReadingLength`.

Therefore, the solution is to actually abstract all that DOM modification/updating logic into a function, which you then invoke once the `$.get` promise is resolved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateDom(fileReading) {
        var fileReadingLength = fileReading.length - 1;

        $("#img1").attr({ "src": fileReading[fileReadingLength - 1] });
        $("#img2").attr({ "src": fileReading[1] });

        $("fileReadingLength").text(fileReadingLength);

        for (i = 0; i <= fileReadingLength; i++) {
            $('body').append('<br><img id="img"'+i+' src="'+fileReading[i]+'">')
        }
    }

    $.get('output.txt', function(data) {
        updateDom(data.split(','));
    });
});
```